# Android AppCompat-v7 and Firestore gradle conflict

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-firestore

So I have the following gradle entry:
[image]

If I remove the firestore-part, it syncs just fine.

What am I missing?

[EDIT] This is what the error says:
[image]

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @AlexMamo: edited the question

Comment: Have you tried to add `implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'` and `implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an warning because Firebase still use old version of dependency. Simply add this dependencies the warning will be removed.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
```